# Problema na criação de classe C# no Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Olá, tudo bem?
Poderia me ajudar? Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Quando crio uma classe C# pelo VS Code, ela roda normalmente; mas ao criar mais de uma, gera-se um problema de instruções de nível superior. Pelo que eu entendi, só uma classe pode ter o main, pode mostrar dados. Mas como estudar se não vou poder rodar meus códigos? A única forma seria criar uma nova pasta (p/ a nova classe) toda vez que for estudar um novo conteúdo?
Imagem abaixo mostrando o problema.[image: não é possível rodar a segunda classe; e o console não funciona na segunda classe também]

Comment: Obrigado, pessoal. Ajudou bastante! Agora entendo como funciona no C#. Era isso. Valeu!

Comment: Show! Se ajudou marque uma das respostas como aceita, assim ajuda outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do Leandro Paixão, na versão 6 em diante do .NET utilizão o conceito de "**Top Level Statements**" ou em português Intruções de Nível Superior, este conceito ele remove a necessidade explicita de um método de entrada principal que conhecemos como Main. No .NET apenas 1 classe por projeto pode conter ou utilizar desta abordagem por isso seu exemplo apresenta o erro do Print. Para maiores informações sobre Instruções de nível superior segue 2 links da documentação da Microsoft sobre:

[Tutorial: explorar ideias usando instruções de nível superior para criar código conforme você aprende](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements)

[Instruções de nível superior – programas sem Main métodos](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isso você terá que utilizar o conceito de `Solutions` dentro do `VS Code`.
Assim você terá uma estrutura similar a isso:

+ Curso de C# (Solution) 
+-- Aula 1 (Projeto)
+-- Aula 2 (Projeto)
+-- Aula 3 (Projeo)

Onde **Curso de** C# é a sua `Solution` e **Aula 1**, **Aula 2** e **Aula 3**, são os **projetos** (que cada um pode conter um `Main`)

Você pode ler:

- [documentação de templates para o VS Code](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x)
- [Conceito de solutions Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/ide/creating-solutions-and-projects?view=vs-2022)
- [Resposta no SO Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45907053/8469314)